# php claims my defined variable is undefined

Tags: php, variables, undefined

My php is a little rusty but this is boggling my mind right now. I googled this and read all the stackoverflow questions I could find that looked related, but those all seemed to have legitimate undefined variables in them. That leads me to believe that mine is the same problem, but no amount of staring at the simple bit of code I have reduced this to seems to get me anywhere. Please someone give me my dunce cap and tell me what I did wrong!

```
<?php
//test for damn undefined variable error

$msgs = "";

function add_msg($msg){
  $msgs .= "<div>$msg</div>";
}
function print_msgs(){
  print $msgs;
}

add_msg("test");
add_msg("test2");
print_msgs();
?>
```

This gives me the following, maddening output:

> Notice: Undefined variable: msgs in C:\wamp\www\fgwl\php-lib\fgwlshared.php on line 7
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: msgs in C:\wamp\www\fgwl\php-lib\fgwlshared.php on line 7
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: msgs in C:\wamp\www\fgwl\php-lib\fgwlshared.php on line 10

Yes, this is supposed to be a shared file, but at the moment I have stripped it down to just what I pasted. Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's defined at the global scope. Use [`global`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) if you want to use it.

Comment: yep. that did it. looks like i need to brush up on scopes in php. thanks!

Answer (score 14):

```
<?php
$msgs = "";

function add_msg($msg){
  global $msgs;
  $msgs .= "<div>$msg</div>";
}
function print_msgs(){
  global $msgs;
  print $msgs;
}

add_msg("test");
add_msg("test2");
print_msgs();
?>
```

`global` tells that PHP need to use the global variable in the local function [scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

Comment: I upvoted this because it answers the question, but I have to add that it's extremely bad practice to use global variables. think globally, act in local scope. They don't print it on shirts for no good reason.

Comment: you're welcome. But keep the advice Kris gave in your mind. For this example it is clear what is happening, but for big(ger) applications, it might become messy and unclear who is fiddling with which variables and therefore error prone.

Answer (score 5):

Using globals for something like this is a poor practice.  Consider an alternate approach such as the following:

```
class MessageQueue {
  private static $msgs;


  public static function add_msg($msg){
    self::$msgs .= "<div>$msg</div>"; 
  }
  public static function print_msgs(){
    print self::$msgs;
  }
}


MessageQueue::add_msg("test");
MessageQueue::add_msg("test2");
MessageQueue::print_msgs();
```

Answer (score 1):

if you don't want to use globals, you can jast use

```
 function add_msg($msg)
   {
         echo  "<div>$msg</div>";
   }
    add_msg("test");
    add_msg("test2");
```

function, the result will be the same.