# Undefined Variable? But I defined it

Tags: php, variables

Well before anyone claims that theres a duplicate question... (I've noticed that people who can't answer the question tend to run and look for a duplicate, and then report it.)

Here is the duplicate you are looking for:
[php claims my defined variable is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2481382/php-claims-my-defined-variable-is-undefined)

However, this isn't quite a duplicate. It gives me a solution, but I'm not really looking for this particular solution.

Here is my problem:

`Notice: Undefined variable: custom`

Now here is my code:

```
                $headers = apache_request_headers(); // Request the visitor's headers.
                $customheader = "Header: 7ddb6ffab28bb675215a7d6e31cfc759"; //This is what the header should be.
                        foreach ($headers as $header => $value) { 
                                $custom .= "$header: $value"; 
}
```

Clearly, $custom is defined. According to the other question, it's a global and should be marked as one. But how is it a global? And how can I make it a (non-global)? The script works fine, it still displays what its supposed to and acts correctly, but when I turn on error messages, it simply outputs that notice as well. I suppose its not currently *necessary* to fix it, but I'd like to anyway, as well as know why its doing this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
$custom .= "$header: $value";
```

You are appending to $custom, but until the first run through the loop, the value in $custom is undefined.

Put a `$custom = '';` before the loop and the error should go away.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see an initial definition for `$custom` there - I see you concatenating to it, but you never give it an initial value.

Put in a line `$custom = '';` before the foreach loop.