# Variables Undefined when in Function

Tags: php, variables, undefined

I am working on a project, and I am getting undefined errors for $host, $dbname, $user, and $pass.

But the errors only occur when those are inside of the dbConnect() function.

Here's the code (upload.php):

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
require('config.php');

$filename = htmlentities($_FILES['file']['name']);
$tmpname = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$filesize = $_FILES['file']['size'];
$filetype = $_FILES['file']['type'];    

function dbConnect() {

    try {
        global $dbcon;
        $dbcon = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);
    }
    catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}

if (dbConnect()) {
    print('worked');
}
```

config.php:

```
<?php
global $host, $user, $pass, $dbname;

$host =  "localhost"; // MySQL Hostname
$user = "root"; // MySQL User
$pass = "mypass"; // MySQL Password
$dbname = "files";
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [php claims my defined variable is undefined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2481382/php-claims-my-defined-variable-is-undefined) and many, many others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the variables into the function as parameters. Variables declared outside a function are not available inside that function:

```
function dbConnect($user, $pass, $host, $dbname) {

    try {
        global $dbcon;
        $dbcon = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);
    }
# ...
```

Read more about [Variable Scope in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  I understand what you mean now, but it's not printing 'worked' as it should be, per the conditional at the bottom of the script.

Comment: That's because you're not returning anything from your function. That's a separate issue for a separate question. Look up a tutorial on how to return things from functions.

Comment: I'd rather not waste an entire question on something that is most likely very simple, and I am just having a brain-fart.

Comment: I've just told you the answer. You're not returning anything. You're testing a void value with your `if` condition. You have to return something that evaluates to `true` if you expect your `if` condition to succeed.

Comment: Are you saying that instantiating a PDO object is not ever going to evaluate to true?

Comment: ***You're not returning anything from your function***.

Comment: I realize that. What needs to be returned in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare those vars GLOBAL inside dbConnect too.

```
function dbConnect() {
  try {
        global $dbcon;
        global $host, $user, $pass, $dbname;
        $dbcon = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);
  }
  catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
  }
}
```

**EDIT**

Yes, globals aren't a really good idea - they hinder code reuse and "pollute" the namespace, you never known which variables are there and which aren't, and risk changing a variable which was used somewhere else.

A better way to approach the problem would be to pass the required information as "parameters". The same applies to the return value, which could be a resource (if everything went well) or a string representing an error message.

```
function dbConnect($host, $dbname, $user = 'nobody', $pass = '') {
  try {
        return new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);
  }
  catch (PDOException $e) {
        return $e->getMessage();
  }
}
```

You would call such a function passing the parameters and checking its output, which if everything went well, is expected to be an object:

```
if (!is_object($conn = dbConnect($host, $dbname, $user, $pass) {
   die("There was an error: $conn");
}
```

Another advantage of parameters is that you can have default values for parameters (e.g., if you wrote dbConnect($host, $dbname), the function would "understand" and use 'nobody' and an empty password for the remaining parameters).

Comment: Global variables may technically solve the problem, but they are *not* the way to fix this.

Comment: Thank you, lserni, however, I'd really like to learn what's going on, and the proper way to fix it, instead of simply "patching" the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you use an array to store your connection string info.

First, create a function in your `config.php` page that returns the necessary DB connection string info.  To use, you would simply declare a variable within `upload.php` of `$dbconfig` that stores the values returned from the `loadDBConfig()` function in your `config.php` file.  You will then execute the `dbConnect()` function by declaring your `$dbcon` variable and setting the value to `dbConnect()`.  This will return the result of your function to the variable, which you can then check for the desired result.

This solution removes the need for global variables and improves the organization.

*Note: Your entire DB interaction should technically be moved to a class for improved portability.*

**upload.php**:

```
...
function dbConnect() {
    $dbconfig = loadDBConfig();
    try {
        $dburl = "mysql:host=" . $dbconfig['host'] . ";dbname=" . $dbconfig['dbname'];
        return new PDO($dburl, $dbconfig['user'], $dbconfig['pass']); 
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
 }  

$dbcon = dbConnect();
...
```

**config.php**:

```
<?php 
function loadDBConfig(){
    $host =  "localhost"; // MySQL Hostname 
    $user = "root"; // MySQL User 
    $pass = "mypass"; // MySQL Password 
    $dbname = "files"; 

    return array('host' => $host, 'user' => $user,  'pass' => $pass, 'dbname' => $dbname);
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!  I really appreciate the example and explanation!  I will keep that in mind next time!